# "insert into" is overwriting data

Tags: hadoop, hive, ddl, dml

internet is not helping and my knowledge on subject is limited.

I have a table with below schema :

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `db.temp_entries`(
  `id` bigint, 
  `random_id` string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcSerde' 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  'hdfs://xxxx/xxxxx/xxx/temp_entries'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'COLUMN_STATS_ACCURATE'='{\"BASIC_STATS\":\"true\"}', 
  'numFiles'='1', 
  'numRows'='1', 
  'orc.compress'='ZLIB', 
  'rawDataSize'='115', 
  'totalSize'='381', 
  'transient_lastDdlTime'='1532514067')
```

Here are the insert queries m using :

Query 1

```
insert into `db.temp_entries`
            values (1, 'P1804010001249002159939')
```

Query 2

```
insert into `db.temp_entries`
            values (2, 'P1804010001495232931398'),
            (3, 'P1804010002374640308088'),
            (4, 'P1804010009196709498065')
```

I am generating this through a python script and doing the `insert` through python `pyhive` package -> `from pyhive import hive`

Although m not using `insert overwrite`, data of `Query#1` is being overwritten by `Query#2`. Is there something wrong in my aproach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the backquotes `` around the table name.

Query 1

```
insert into db.temp_entries
            values (1, 'P1804010001249002159939')
```

Query 2

```
insert into db.temp_entries
            values (2, 'P1804010001495232931398'),
            (3, 'P1804010002374640308088'),
            (4, 'P1804010009196709498065')
```